# Fortran MPI doesn't run on all of the given number of Processors

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I'm currently running a program in which a model grid must be processed. When I want to run the program using eg. 10 processors as workers (`mpirun -np 11 -machinefile host civil_mpi.exe`), only 3 peocessors run the program and the rest stop at the beginning of the program without any error!

If I decrease the size of the model grid, everything works correctly. The total RAM of the machine is over 30 GB, and the size of the Memory needed for each process (based on the model grid size) is less than 1 GB, so theoretically there should be no Problem with the RAM. Could anyone help me on this case?

The OS is Linux OpenSuse, and I'm running the MPI on a machine with 16 Dual-core CPUs. The code is:

```
      call MPI_INIT(ierror)

      call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, procid, ierror)

      call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierror)
      nworker = nproc - 1

      call mpi_get_processor_name (procname, len, ierror)


      n_slice = 280
      ny0(1) = 1
      ny(1) = 2 

      do i = 2,n_slice
       ny0(i) = ny0(i-1) + 2
       ny(i) = ny(i-1) + 2
      end do

      nx = 461
      nx0 = 1
      nz = 421
      nz0 = 1

      nwork = 1

      do i = 1,280
         if(nworker*nwork .lt. n_slice) then
         nwork = nwork + 1
         end if
      end do

      if (procid .eq. masterid) then

      worker_job = 1

      do q = 1,nworker

         iwork = q

         call mpi_send(worker_job, 1, MPI_INTEGER, iwork, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

        call mpi_send(nx0, 1, MPI_INTEGER, iwork, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

        call mpi_send(ny0, 280, MPI_INTEGER, iwork, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)

        call mpi_send(nz0, 1, MPI_INTEGER, iwork, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

        call mpi_send(nx, 1, MPI_INTEGER, iwork, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)

        call mpi_send(ny, 280, MPI_INTEGER, iwork, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

        call mpi_send(nz, 1, MPI_INTEGER, iwork, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)


      worker_job = worker_job + nwork

      end do

      end if

c ------------------ worker task -----------

      if (procid .gt. masterid) then
c      write(*,*)'processor',procid,'is working....'

      call mpi_recv(worker_job, 1, MPI_INTEGER, masterid, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)

      call mpi_recv(nx0, 1, MPI_INTEGER, masterid, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)

      call mpi_recv(ny0, 280, MPI_INTEGER, masterid, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)

      call mpi_recv(nz0, 1, MPI_INTEGER, masterid, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)

      call mpi_recv(nx, 1, MPI_INTEGER, masterid, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)

      call mpi_recv(ny, 280, MPI_INTEGER, masterid, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)

      call mpi_recv(nz, 1, MPI_INTEGER, masterid, tag,
     $                MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)


       do j = worker_job, worker_job + nwork - 1

         if (j .le. 280) then
         write(*,*) '****************processor',procid,'is working'
         call rawmig(j,nx0,ny0(j),nz0,nx,ny(j),nz)
         end if  
       end do
      end if

      call mpi_finalize(ierror)

      end
```

Comment: You should post at least some code and details about your OS and MPI implementation. There are tons of reasons why this could go wrong.

Comment: The post is edited and now with the Code.

Comment: Did you run `dmesg` on all your hosts ? Did you see the oom-killer in action ? A simple trick is to `mpirun civil_mpi.sh` where `civil_mpi.sh` does `./civil_mpi.exe; echo mpi task exited with status $?`. That should tell you hiw the mpi tasks returned

Comment: Which MPI are you using? For example with Intel MPI you could try using -check when running the program and see if that tells you anything.

Comment: I've just tried it with dmesg as: mpirun -np 11 -machinefile host civil_mpi.exe dmesg -K but no error message come from the processors. Also no oom-killer. On the other Hand, I see the check message on the Display (processor #x is working) which means the last do Loop, where the subroutine in called, starts for all processors!

Comment: It's Intel MPI, but when I try the -check option within the mpirun command, it ´won't be recognized as an Standard option!

Comment: Note you can replace `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` with `MPI_Bcast()` in order to make your program mote efficient and readable

Comment: The MPI_Bcast also also doesn't work! I think there must be something wring with the Memory sharing between processors, as when I make the model a bit smaller, everything works perfect.

Comment: Can you post a trimmed version of your program that can be compiled and used to evidence the issue ? Note you cannot `MPI_Bcast(worker_job)` but you have to deduce it from `procid` instead

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Thank you all for the comments, finally I've realized that one of the Matrices in the main program must have been synchronized with the new dementions comming from processors! Gilles Gouaillardet, I was trying to make a shortend and readable Version of the program to post it after your Suggestion and during that I saw that this matrice is in the form to build an Output with iy=ny0,ny (the varying Dimension) which must have been iy=1,2. But first of all, the matrice dimensions in the definitions must have been corrected, and because it was defined with the directly comming variables from each processor, some of the processors were stoped without any erorr message!

Comment: good to know ! when you write 'stopped without any error message', do you mean these MPI task basically hang ? or do you mean these MPI task exit and this goes unnoticed by `mpirun` ?

Comment: In fact the MPI was working with no Problem, but rather than the first (or the first two processors, the rest were stopping without any error when they started to run the main program. These cores were trying to call the main program with a higher ny0 and ny, but since in the main program the Matrix dimensions were not corrected to translate the comming ny from the MPI (eg. for ny0=450 & ny=452, ny in the main program must have been interpreted as 2 (=452-450)), because of the Matrix dimensions, the Memory was full (the reason to split the main program via MPI) and the process stoped.

Comment: And for sure, the first processor was running but with the wrong Output!

Comment: This was what I could recognize prety fast, but the worse Thing was that a vector was defined as k(nx*ny), and I had changed it to k(nx *ny-ny0+1), a stupid mistake about braces, it must have been k(nx*(ny-ny0+1,nz)).